# How to add elements to a vector based on another vector position wise in R

Tags: r, loops, vector

I have a positive integer value vector C which is of length 192. I want to generate another vector based on this vector C. The new vector to be created is called B (same length as C). The algorithm for creation is:

Whenever a value above 0 is observed in C, add the same value 12 places back in the vector B. For example, if the first 15 entries of C are 0 and the 16th entry is 3, then I want to add the value 3, 12 positions back (which is 16-12=position 4) in vector B. The vector B would be generated in this way over all values of C.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! The vector C can be obtained by the R library "outbreaks" and the data file from that package is ebola_kikwit_1995$onset.

Comment: What did you try? Creating a `for`-loop combined with an `if`-statement is a good start. Please show where you got stuck.

Comment: It works best if you show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Only then we can really help you. Also, to help you it would be helpful if you give us a sample vector B and C that you create with R code and additionally provide us with the answer you expect from your algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem to be very tricky. An index vector and a `for` loop will do what the question asks for.

```
library("outbreaks")

i <- which(ebola_kikwit_1995$onset > 0)
i <- i[i > 12]

ebola_kikwit_1995$B <- 0L
for(j in i){
  ebola_kikwit_1995$B[j] <- ebola_kikwit_1995$onset[j] + ebola_kikwit_1995$B[j - 12]
}

ebola_kikwit_1995$B
#  [1]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# [28]  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
# [55]  0  0  0  0  0  1  1  1  0  0  0  0  3  0  0  0  1  2  0  2  0  2  0  1  0  0  0
# [82]  0  0  0  0  4  0  3  1  3  1  0  1  1  1  1  1  5  3  0  5  7  2  2  5  3  2  8
#[109]  5  9  5  4 10 10 13 14 20 10  9 16  7 14 13 10 18 13 17 21 31 13 21 21 15 17 16
#[136] 18 22 18 18 24 35 16 22 23 18 18 19 21 26 21 23 26 37 17  0 25  0  0 21  0  0  0
#[163] 25 28  0 18  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
#[190]  0  0  0
```